# XSLT split string to tags

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to transform this XML

```
<params>
    <param>
        <name>parameter 1</name>
        <type>values</type>
        <values>"10""","20""","30""","40"""</values>
    <param>
    <param>
        <name>parameter 2</name>
        <type>values</type>
        <values>100mm,200mm,300mm,400mm</values>
    <param>
</params>
```

to this XML

```
<params>
    <param>
        <name>parameter 1</name>
        <type>values</type>
        <values>
            <value>
                <name><![CDATA[10"]]></name>
            <value>
            <value>
                <name><![CDATA[20"]]></name>
            <value>
            <value>
                <name><![CDATA[30"]]></name>
            <value>
            <value>
                <name><![CDATA[40"]]></name>
            <value>
        </values>
    <param>
    <param>
        <name>parameter 2</name>
        <type>values</type>
        <values>
            <value>
                <name><![CDATA[100mm]]></name>
            <value>
            <value>
                <name><![CDATA[200mm]]></name>
            <value>
            <value>
                <name><![CDATA[300mm]]></name>
            <value>
            <value>
                <name><![CDATA[400mm]]></name>
            <value>
        </values>
    <param>
</params>
```

using this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <params>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </params>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="params/param">
    <param>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="name" /></name>
        <type><xsl:value-of select="type" /></type>
        <values>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="values"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </values>
    </param>
</xsl:template>

<!-- tokenize -->
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
        <value>
            <name>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, '&quot;,&quot;')"  />    
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>                   
            </name>
        </value>

        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&quot;,&quot;')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and I have few problems:

1. the last of values is empty
2. I dont know ho to remove first and last quotation

>

```
<values>
    <value>
        <name><![CDATA["10""]]></name>
    </value>
    <value>
        <name><![CDATA[20""]]></name>
    </value>
    <value>
        <name><![CDATA[30""]]></name>
    </value>
    <value>
        <name><![CDATA[]]></name>
    </value>
</values>
```

3. values are presented as strings in two versions and I dont know how to write a condition to decide which separator use in tokenize

I need to do something like this:

```
if (first char = ")
    trim " from begining and end
    split string by ","
    foreach value replace "" to "
else
    explode string by ,
```

But I dont know how to do that with XSLT.

Can you please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="name"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="values">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />            
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <value>
            <name>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with($token, '&quot;') and substring($token, string-length($token)) = '&quot;'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($token, 2, string-length($token) - 2)"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </name>
        </value>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchString">""</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="replaceString">"</xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,$searchString)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$searchString)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replaceString"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$searchString)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="$searchString"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replaceString" select="$replaceString"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: With a few modifications works for me perfectly. Thanks a lot mate.